# Iterar sobre un array de objeto en js

Tags: javascript, typescript

Tengo el siguiente objeto:

```
    obj = [
{ 1: 20, 2: 26, 3: 14},
{ 1: 12, 2: 25, 3: 15},
{ 1: 14, 2: 13, 3: 19},
{ 1: 16, 2: 32, 3: 21}
]
```

y deseo multiplicar por dos cada una de las posiciones y luego sumarlas de acuerdo a cada posición, me explico:

multiplico cada valor por 2 y este es el resultado parcial:

```
    obj = [
{ 1: 40, 2: 52, 3: 28},
{ 1: 24, 2: 50, 3: 30},
{ 1: 28, 2: 26, 3: 38},
{ 1: 32, 2: 72, 3: 42}
]
```

luego debo sumar cada clave y adicionar el total agregando un nuevo array al final dentro del objeto inicial, y este debe ser el resultado final:

```
    obj = [
{ 1: 20, 2: 26, 3: 14},
{ 1: 12, 2: 25, 3: 15},
{ 1: 14, 2: 13, 3: 19},
{ 1: 16, 2: 32, 3: 21},
{ 1: 104, 2: 200, 3: 138}
]
```

Comment: Y qué es lo que has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: He intentado, hace un for y dentro de ese for un map he iterar sobre cada valor obteniendo los valores con un  ```Object.values()``` pero allí me he quedado estancado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
let obj = [
{ 1: 20, 2: 26, 3: 14},
{ 1: 12, 2: 25, 3: 15},
{ 1: 14, 2: 13, 3: 19},
{ 1: 16, 2: 32, 3: 21}
];

let sumaObject = obj.reduce((a, b) => {
    for (const key in b) {
      if (b.hasOwnProperty(key))
        a[key] = (a[key] || 0) + b[key] * 2;
    }
    return a;
  }, {});

obj.push(sumaObject);

console.log(obj);
```

Básicamente se hace todo con el método [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) de JavaScript. Para este caso sólo es necesario enviarle 2 parámetros `(a, b)` el primero es el acumulador, que será un objeto vacío.

El segundo parámetro será cada objeto en el array, es decir, `b` tomará los valores de `{ 1: 20, 2: 26, 3: 14}`, `{ 1: 12, 2: 25, 3: 15}`, es por ello que se deben recorrer con un `for`.

Posterior a ello, la lógica es simple. Primero debes saber que el objeto que tienes, cuenta con las propiedades `1, 2 y 3`, por lo que, con [hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) preguntamos:

```
if (b.hasOwnProperty(key)) // El objeto tiene la propiedad 1, 2, 3 ?
```

Si es así, ingresamos al cuerpo del if y, en el objeto vacío `a` creamos esa propiedad que se irá acumulando:

```
a[key] = (a[key] || 0) + b[key] * 2;
```

Al finalizar simplemente retornamos el objeto acumulado:

```
return a;
```

Dado que lo que retornamos es un objeto, sólo queda añadirlo al objeto principal el cual ya está modificado:

```
obj.push(sumaObject);
```

Comment: Así lo había intentado, pero necesito es añadir es el resultado al objeto inicial, como lo pido en la pregunta {a: 20 ...}

Comment: Listo, sólo era una línea de código. Ahora obtienes lo que deseas

Comment: @L.Flor si estás utilizando ES6, recomendaría cambiar `let` por `const` ya que ningún objeto cambia su valor en la ejecución. Saludos.

Comment: @L.Flor gracias, había creado uno, pero veo que el  tuyo quedó mas optimizado